# Find and replace tab to spaces for a particular pattern in a unix file which is tab-delimited as field separator

Tags: perl, shell, unix, sed, ksh

Ok. The Header might be confusing but to elaborate i have a file in unix which is already a tab delimited one and i am trying to bcp in that.But the problem is in one column where some random values has tab inside it .But its not actually random. The tab in that column are inside only double quote values. This extra tab can be just after a double quote or just before and in between a word inside double quotes.

So i want to replace these tabs to space.

For e.g

```
HAPPINESS       ALEXIS JORDAN   "HAPPINESS      "       CASH    024     Producer                ABRAMUS QUARTERLY       HAPPINESS       D658    Columbia        D658    Columbia        C283    Columbia Records Group  1Q15
HAPPINESS       ALEXIS JORDAN   "HAPPINESS      ALWAYS" CASH    024     Producer                ABRAMUS QUARTERLY       HAPPINESS       D658    Columbia        D658    Columbia        C283    Columbia Records Group  1Q15
HAPPINESS       DEADMAU5/ALEXIS JORDAN  "       HAPPINESS       "       CASH    024     Producer                ABRAMUS QUARTERLY       HAPPINESS       D658    Columbia        D658    Columbia        C283    Columbia Records Group  1Q15
```

Please find the above text for your reference. 
Please Help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Forgot to add there is a tab in each line inside double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `gnu-awk` commandto convert tabs inside the quotes:

```
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]+"|[^\t]+' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /^"/)
       gsub(/\t/, "   ", $i)} 1' OFS='\t' file
```

`FPAT='"[^"]+"|[^\t]+'` break input to fields either in double quotes or if they're separated by a tab.

Output with `cat-vt` of given sample:

```
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]+"|[^\t]+' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /^"/) gsub(/\t/, "   ", $i)} 1' OFS='\t' file|cat -vt
HAPPINESS^IALEXIS^IJORDAN^I"HAPPINESS   "^ICASH^I024^IProducer^IABRAMUS^IQUARTERLY^IHAPPINESS^ID658^IColumbia^ID658^IColumbia^IC283^IColumbia^IRecords^IGroup^I1Q15
HAPPINESS^IALEXIS^IJORDAN^I"HAPPINESS   ALWAYS"^ICASH^I024^IProducer^IABRAMUS^IQUARTERLY^IHAPPINESS^ID658^IColumbia^ID658^IColumbia^IC283^IColumbia^IRecords^IGroup^I1Q15
HAPPINESS^IDEADMAU5/ALEXIS^IJORDAN^I"   HAPPINESS   "^ICASH^I024^IProducer^IABRAMUS^IQUARTERLY^IHAPPINESS^ID658^IColumbia^ID658^IColumbia^IC283^IColumbia^IRecords^IGroup^I1Q15
```

Comment: Thanks fo the response. But the above command will replace tab before 1st double quote and after the 2nd double quote also.

I dont want that.. I want to replace any tab within two double quotas and just to add the file is already tab delimited one.

TIA.
Ayush

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that as rom the output in my answer you can see that tab before first double quote i.e. `"HAPPINESS` wasn't replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Perl:

```
perl -pe 's{"\K(.*?)(?=")}{$1 =~ tr/\t/ /r}eg' filename
```

This replaces everything matched by the regex `"\K(.*?)(?=")` with the result of the expression `$1 =~ tr/\t/ /r`. The `eg` modifiers are necessary to replace `g`lobally (in case more than one quoted string is in a line) and with replacement `e`xpressions evaluated.

Things to note:

- Everything before `\K` has to be there for something to be a match but makes it not actually part of the match.
- `(?=")` is a lookahead term; it matches an empty string if it is followed by `"`
- `.*?` matches any string non-greedily, i.e. the shortest fitting match is taken rather than the longest

The regex therefore matches everything between a `"` and the next `"` and captures it as `$1`. The expression in the replacement clause returns the value of this capture with tabs replaced by spaces, and it is shoehorned in where the original string used to be.

Comment: I tried with the above code. and i got this ..

 perl -pe 's{"\K(.*?)(?=")}{$1 =~ tr/\t/ /r}eg' consolidated_ppb_20151001.txt21
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "tr/\t/ /r"
syntax error at -e line 1, near "tr/\t/ /r"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

I do not have much idea on perl.. Please help.  TIA

Comment: i did some digging and found that my perl is of older version. so i have removed /r but now i am getting "Modification of a read-only value attempted at -e line 1, <> line 1" error.

Please help.

Comment: The `r` modifier to `tr`, `s` etc. is there since Perl 5.14. If your Perl is older, use `perl -pe 's{"\K(.*?)(?=")}{$x = $1; $x =~ tr/\t/ /; $x}eg' filename`. Making a copy is necessary because `$1` is a read-only value and `=~ tr/\t/ /` without `r` attempts to modify the left-hand side.